# Конвертер видео для сервера

Tags: python, moviepy

Столкнулся с проблемой нужен простой конвертер видео для сервера.
Нашел статейку, сделал по аналогии чтобы проверить, но у меня файл просто открывается и сразу закрывается.

Предварительно скачал библиотеки `pip install moviepy`

пример такой

```
import moviepy.editor as mp

fname = input("Укажите название файла: ")
clip = mp.VideoFileClip(fname + ".mp4")
clip.write_videofile("2.mp4")
```

Что не так, не пойму?

Comment: По-моему, круче [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) ничего нет :)

Comment: да и с кодом все "так", ну за исключением того, что он просто перегоняет из `.mp4` в `.mp4`

Comment: @АлексейР gstreamer круче